# Finding right instalation when using booster pump together with gravity storage tank

Tags: pump, water-tank

I have two ideas for connecting  booster pump(s) to roof storage water tank:

First scenario: use the pump to
fill storage tank, and tank to supply water to the building.
In this case two separate inlet and outlet lines are installed, one to connect the tank with pump and and the other from tank outlet to home consumers.

Second scenario: use a common line that connects both consumers and pump to storage tank, and a three way on tank to separate  inlet and outlet nozzles and connect them to the common line.

---

I think the first scenario is more general, that is seen in codes, but I think the second idea is still possible and it could have few benefits in some cases.

---

To make it more specific, the building have 5 stages with 3 apartments each, and it needs at least two 2000 litrs water storage tanks on top and one 1000 liter tank on ground.

---

Exact Question : I want to know exactly when to use each configuration plus pros and cons of them?

Comment: I suspect this is ultimately something that will be decided by your local building code authority.

Comment: In my case the code do not force a special configuration

Comment: Why would you want to pump water through an outlet that is feeding all the apt.  Seem it would cause water flow issues when someone wants to use water and you are forcing water up the pipe at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

@mfarver many countries have no codes for this situation, I understand the need to push water up to a tank in many areas the pressure is not there to push it up several stories. I would suggest a 2 pump system with a small pressure tank , the valves and control required for a single pump system would cost much more much as a 2nd pump and have more potential problems.
A single question is preferred but a small pressure tank and pump can supply the multiple homes a pump with a simple limit switch to pump water up to the tank until it is full is the simplest method. Simple lasts and has less problems.
Down vote reversed.